# Structure database to send friend requests to the people user haven't send

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need to implement a firebase friend request system. And it is not a normal friendship system. So I have a list of users. Every user has a "score" field.
And a user should be able to send requests to the users with the highest score. 
And no duplicate requests allowed.

So to do this I have to query for the users with the highest score using "orderBy("score")". But the problem is I cannot find if they are already friends this way.

```
friends = {
  "userId 1": {
    "userID 2": true,
    "userId 4": true,
    "userId 5": true,
    "userID 15": true
  },
  "userId 2": {
    "userID 1": true,
    "userID 3": true,
    "userID 4": true
  }
}

users = {
  "userID 1": {
    "name": "alex",
    "score": 12
  },
  "userID 2": {
    "name": "alex",
    "score": 40
  },
  "userID 3": {
    "name": "alex",
    "score": 30
  },
  "userID 4": {
    "name": "alex",
    "score": 9
  }
}
```

so I am asking for a way to filter a particular set of ** non-friends** ordered according to their score in relation to a particular user.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Currently, I can order by score. But cannot filter non-friends.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Query myQuery = myRef.orderByKey("score).limitToFirst(20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Firebase's query model to filter by the absence of a property. You will have to store a lot of duplicate data for non-friends (which seems unreasonable here even by NoSQL standards), or load the top scores across all uses, and then exclude the non-friends client-side.